# In AngularJS how can i Store data into local storage on click of reload button in the browser?

Tags: angularjs, angular, onclick, local-storage

In AngularJS how can i store data into the localstorage on click of reload button in the browser?

I tried with the following code.still, it's not working

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) 
{
    var $body = angular.element(document.body);   

    var $localStorage = $body.injector().get('$localStorage');
    var logoutService = $body.injector().get('logoutService');

    if (typeof event == 'undefined') 
    {
        event = window.event;
    }

        else if (event.type == 'beforeunload') 
        {
            if(startAppCtrl.persDet !=undefined)
            {
                $localstorage.setItem('persDet',startAppCtrl.persDet);
            }else
            {
                startAppCtrl.persDet=$localStorage.getItem('persDet');   
            }        


        }
}
```

Comment: use localStorage.setItem('token', token); to set the data in local storage, to get the data from local storage use this localStorage.getItem('token'); , to remove use this localStorage.removeItem('token');

Comment: @Mathi did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You could add an event listener to the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  $window.localStorage.setItem('varName', varValue);
};
```

Where `$window` is a reference to the `window` object passed as a parameter in your controller function.

```
.controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $window
){

  $window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    $window.localStorage.setItem('varName', varValue);
  };

  // don't forget to remove the listener when the controller is out of scope
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      delete $window.onbeforeunload;
  });

});
```

You could also use `ngStorage` if you don't want to access the vanilla localStorage api on window.

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

```
angular.module('app', [
            'ngStorage'
        ]).controller('Ctrl', function(
            $scope,
            $localStorage,
            $window
        ){
          ....
          $window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            $localStorage.setItem('varName', varValue);
          };
          ....
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

## Example : related from $localStorage

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LocalStorage Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Localstorage Dependency ngStorage -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //User this module  in your Angular APP
            var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
            //$localStorage is a services 
            app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
                $scope.Save = function () {
                    $localStorage.LocalMsg = "You are using localStorage (JEET)";
                    $sessionStorage.SessionMsg = "You are using session storage (JEET)";
                }
                $scope.Get = function () {
                    console.log($localStorage.LocalMsg + "\n" + $sessionStorage.SessionMsg);
                }
            });
        </script>
        <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
            <input type="button" value="Reload" ng-click="Save()" />
            <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="Get()" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling local storage through service using AngularJS.

**Local storage service :**

Common factory service that will save and return the saved local storage data based on the key.

```
app.factory('storageService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    return {
        get: function(key) {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        save: function(key, data) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, data);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**In controller :**

Inject the storageService dependency in the controller to set and get the data from the local storage.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['storageService',function(storageService) {

  // Save session data to storageService
  storageService.save('key', 'value');

  // Get saved session data from storageService
  var localStorageData = storageService.get('key');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The LocalStorage API gives front-end web developers access to a simple key-value datastore that can be used to save data on a users computer.

You have various methods to set the value and to retrieve them back .

Example :
For storing the values in local storage you can use the following :

```
// Functions
localStorage.setItem('name', 'Matt West');

// Object
localStorage.name = 'Matt West';

// Array
localStorage['name'] = 'Matt West';
```

For retrieving the values you can use

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object containing save and fetch methods

```
//localStorage persistence
var STORAGE_KEY = "items";
//localStorage.clear();
var itemStorage = {
  fetch: function() {
    var saved = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    var items = saved !== null
      ? JSON.parse(saved)
      : [
          {
            username: "Jondi Rose",
            fullname: "Alfred Jond Rose",
            point: 1234,
            notes: "super user"
          },
          {
            username: "Dulal",
            fullname: "Jonathan Smith",
            point: 23,
            notes: "new user"
          }
        ];
    items.forEach(function(item, index) {
      item.id = index;
    });
    itemStorage.uid = items.length;
    return items;
  },
  save: function(items) {
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(items));
  }
};
```

on `$destroy` call this method.
You can use `$routeChangeStart` if working on SPA.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    //callback
});
```